# Meteor: mongodb update not working

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What could be wrong with this update function?

```
fixrecs2 = function() {

      var arr = myColl.find({ d: 1 }).fetch();

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

       var code = arr[i].c;

       var rec = myOtherColl.findOne( { cc: code });

       if (rec) {

          c(rec._id)

          myOtherColl.update( {_id: rec._ID }, { $set: {dt: "ant"}  } ); 
       }

  }

console.log(i + " records processed.");
}
```

I have never had trouble updating my documents before in this way. Checking the output in the console, I can tell that all the records that I expect to find are there.  I can see their _id values printed by console.log().  But the dt field does not get updated.  In some cases, the dt field already exists, in some cases it doesn't, but update is supposed to add a field if it's not there, right?

I have tried adding a callback, but it did not seem to run. (I have not been able to find a good callback example for the update function.)  In any case, according to the docs, I should get an error message in the console if update fails.  I'm still running the insecure package, so there's no allow or deny rules to worry about.  I'm really stumped by this!

Comment: Have you tried `myOtherColl.update({ '_id' : rec._ID }, { $set: { dt: "ant" } })`, with quotes around `_id`? Most examples on [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#update) page are using quotes. Another thing, are you sure `rec._ID` is an ObjectID?

Comment: Of course, that's it!  The objectID field is:  _id  not  _ID.  I had it right in this line:     c( rec._id )  but not in the update command.  Thanks for spotting this!

Comment: Okay, I added an answer, to resolve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case, turned out to be a simple misspelling, `rec._ID` is not the same as `rec._id`. This was likely overlooked due to the common capitalization of MongoDB's `ObjectID`.